¿Cambiar el icono de una extensión de Chrome?
Estoy desarrollando una extensión en Chrome, y quiero que el icono de la extensión en la barra de herramientas cambie si un elemento está presente en la página.
De momento lo que tengo es bastante simple, una extensión vacía que comprueba si el elemento existe y cambia el icono. De hecho, para simplificar más aún el tema, que cambia el icono siempre.
Esta es la estructura de la extensión:
---- Extension
     |--- images
     |    |---- icon.png
     |    |---- icon2.png
     |
     |--- scripts
     |    |---- script.js
     |  
     |---- manifest.json

Este es mi manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Nombre",
  "description": "Descripción",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["scripts/script.js"],
      "matches": ["https://miweb/*"]
    }
  ]
}

Y en scripts.js sólo tengo:
chrome.action.setIcon({
  path : "images/icon2.png"
});

Cuando cargo la extensión en Chrome y abro una página donde actuará recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setIcon')

Depurando, efectivamente no existe action por lo que es normal que reciba ese error. Buscando en Internet, encontré soluciones para versiones antiguas donde decían de usar browserAction o pageAction (ninguna de ellas funcionó.)
También intenté mandando un mensaje en runtime del siguiente modo:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (msg.action === "updateIcon") {
    chrome.action.setIcon({ path: "images/icon2.png" });
  }
});

// ...

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  action: 'updateIcon'
  value: true
});

Pero cuando hago eso, recibo otro error diferente:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

En Stack Overflow en inglés vi que alguien recomendaba añadir "run_at": "document_start" al content_scripts para evitar este error, pero eso no funcionó tampoco.
¿Se puede cambiar el icono de la extensión en la barra del navegador? ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

La verdad que no sé, pero por lo que he visto, lo usan desde el "background": { "service_worker": "background.js" } aunque en la documentación esto no se especifica en ningún momento.

@Marcos poner el addListener en el service worker es lo que funcionó. Gracias por la sugerencia, deberías ponerla como respuesta.

Creo que el más indicado para responder sos vos, realmente no sé qué fue lo que sí te funcionó, ja! Saludos!

@Marcos ¿Seguro?

100%, no sabría decir porqué desde el service_worker si funciona y tampoco he hecho una extensión para probarlo.


Nota: esta respuesta está basada en el comentario de Marcos en la pregunta.

La solución fue crear un service worker escuchando mensajes. Todos los ingredientes para que funcionase estaban en la propia pregunta, lo único que faltaba era organizarlos bien.
Paso 1: Mover el addListener al service worker (un nuevo fichero llamado sw.js en el directorio scripts). Su contenido sería:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (msg.action === "updateIcon") {
    chrome.action.setIcon({ path: "/images/icon2.png" });
  }
});

Y así, el contenido de script.js se queda en tan solo:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  action: 'updateIcon'
  value: true
});

Paso 2: Añadir el service worker a la raíz del manifest, indicando que es un script que corre en el background:
"background": { 
  "service_worker": "sw.js" 
}

De este modo, el fichero manifest.json se ve así:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Nombre",
  "description": "Descripción",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["scripts/script.js"],
      "matches": ["https://miweb/*"]
    }
  ],
  "background": { 
    "service_worker": "sw.js" 
  }
}

Y así ya funciona.

Pero hice un cambio más. Con el código mostrado arriba, el icono de la extensión cambia para todas las ventanas y pestañas. Quiero que cambie sólo para la pestañas que cumplen el requisito. Para ello hice un pequeño cambio en el service worker, que comprueba la pestaña activa y le pasa el id a setIcon para que el icono sólo cambie en dicha pestaña y no en las demás:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (msg.action === "updateIcon") {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, ([tab] => {
      chrome.action.setIcon({ path: "/images/icon2.png" });
      sendResponse(true);
    });
  }
});

